# What is it called when you replace a word with a phrase?

Tags: obscure-terms

Replacing a word with a phrase, but not in the case of a euphemism. Example: replacing "United Nations" with "Headquarters of Peace" so the sentence would be, "It would cause war in the headquarters of peace."

Comment: Hello, Lydia. What is your definition of 'word'? (2) Synonymy is not confined to swappable single orthographic words (but neither does it include offbeat substitutes).

Comment: The term name is metonymy. Thank you though!

Comment: [Metonymy:](https://www.google.com/search?q=metonymy+define&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=w8SdWMXSE8fI8AeTvqCQCQ)"the substitution of the name of an attribute or adjunct for that of the thing meant, for example suit for business executive, or the track for horse racing."

Answer (score 0):

I asked a language professor and the term name is metonymy.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, please restructure it to be a more useful answer to others. Please include a definition, a source, and proper formatting.

Comment: But please first check (on discovering that the word you require is 'metonymy') that the term hasn't been sought on ELU before. It has. Also, I doubt if 'Headquarters of Peace' is recognised as a metonym for the UN (or even the UN Building). I've seen a descriptive juxtaposition: 'It’s known as the headquarters of peace and hope for countries from all around the world to express their views on a range of important international issues.'

Read more: http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/354239#ixzz4YJXSav82 // However, metonyms are usually well recognised figures of speech.